# XStream: How to let xstream.createObjectInputStream() seek to a particular element

Tags: java, xml, xstream, seek

I'm trying to use XStream to import large XML files (~ 1 GB). I want to use an `ObjectInputStream` to read them streaming, but I need that to skip the first element and then move down a couple elements (see below, I need to import the `bag_LVC:Woonplaats` elements).

I'd expect that there is somehow a way to feed xstream a `Reader` or a `InputStream` which has been seeked up to my element of interest. I've tried to create my own `HierarchicalStreamReader` and move it to the right element, but you can only move up and down:

```
HierarchicalStreamReader xpp = new XppDriver().createReader(xmlFile);
xpp.moveDown(); // moves to <xb:antwoord>
xpp.move(); // **would move to <xb:producten>, but it private**
xpp.moveDown(); // moves to <xb:producten>
xpp.moveDown(); // moves to <product_LVC:LVC-product>
st = xstream.createObjectInputStream(xpp);
BagWoonplaats bw = (BagWoonplaats) st.readObject();
```

Does xstream or any of the XPP drivers have any way to let you seek to my element of interest?

## xml

```
<xb:BAG-Extract-Deelbestand-LVC>
  <xb:antwoord>
    <xb:vraag>
    <!-- more elements here -->
    </xb:vraag>
    <xb:producten>
      <product_LVC:LVC-product>
        <bag_LVC:Woonplaats>
          <!-- elements used as fields -->
        </bag_LVC:Woonplaats>
        <bag_LVC:Woonplaats>
          <!-- elements used as fields -->
        </bag_LVC:Woonplaats>
        <!-- and so on -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem was actually very trivial, and I'm almost embarrassed, but let's share the answer for this problem anyway. I didn't get the API for the HierarchicalStreamReader, after digging around in the code of XStream I managed to get an handled to it, this is how it works:

```
    HierarchicalStreamReader xpp = ...;
    while(xpp.hasMoreChildren()) {
        xpp.moveDown();
        // do something with the child element, and recursive into this again if appropriate
        xpp.moveUp();
    }
```

This is recursive method I now use to seek to the appropriate element. The location is specified by a sort of xpath expression (very basic, of course), which I have normalized in advance, into an ArrayList:

```
private void seekToElement(HierarchicalStreamReader xpp, ArrayList<String> xpathishArray) {
    while(xpp.hasMoreChildren()) {
        xpp.moveDown();
        if(xpp.getNodeName().equals(xpathishArray.get(0))) {
            if(xpathishArray.size() > 1) {
                xpathishArray.remove(0);
                seekToElement(xpp, xpathishArray);
            }
            return;
        }
        xpp.moveUp();
    }
}
```